# Dyndle Website giving 404 error

Tags: sites-9.5, dyndle

We have developed website using Tridion Sites 9.5 and Dyndle. Suddenly the website is throwing 404 error and below is the error printed in the DD4T log file.

```
>>GetContentByUrl(/system/redirect-links.html/index.html)
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:30,189 9408593ms Performance            Debug              - GetContentByUrl: about to create query
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:30,189 9408593ms Performance            Debug              - GetContentByUrl: created query
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:30,189 9408593ms Performance            Debug              - GetContentByUrl: added criteria to query
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:30,205 9408608ms Performance            Debug              - GetContentByUrl: about to execute query
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:44,714 9423117ms Performance            Debug              - GetContentByUrl: executed query
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:44,714 9423117ms Performance            Debug              - <<GetContentByUrl(/system/redirect-links.html/index.html)
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:44,730 9423133ms Performance            Debug              - finished loading page content from provider with url /system/redirect-links.html/index.html, has value: False
DEBUG 2023-05-23 14:24:44,730 9423133ms Performance            Debug              - <<TryFindPage (/system/redirect-links.html/index.html
ERROR 2023-05-23 14:24:44,730 9423133ms DefaultLogger          GetDefinitions     - Redirects page is not published. Url : /system/redirect-links.html
```

The redirect page is already published.

[image]

Comment: @Quirijn need your help

Answer (score 1):

The content service was not responding it was healthy but when querying any data it was not responding so we restarted the service and it fixed the issue

Comment: If restarting solved it… the issue probably will come back. I’d recommend having a test that validates the service is responding and triggering an alert whenever it doesn’t. I wouldn’t go as far as automatically restarting the service until you’re comfortable with your tests…